# How to hide the content over view through Animations

Tags: iphone

I am showing a view,on which there is one button.On click of this button I am showing a PopUp view through animation methods defined in Objective C and add an image over Popup view.then on any tap on the view this pop up view is hiding by setting its width and height equal to zero,but the image over it is not hiding.how can I hide it..?
these are methods i am using..

this method is called after click on button..

```
-(void)btnImageClkForPopUp:(id)sender
{  
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.5];
popup_viewforimage.frame=CGRectMake(8, 30, 300, 250);
popup_viewforimage.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

UIImageView *imgview=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 250)];
imgview.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"apple.jpeg"];
[popup_viewforimage addSubview:imgview];

[self.view addSubview:popup_viewforimage];   
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

these two methods are called to hide this after making a tap touch on view

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
{ 
 return NO;
}
return YES;   
}

-(void)hidekeyboard
{
 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.5];
 popup_viewforimage.frame=  CGRectMake(15, 65, 0, 0);
 popup_viewforimage.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
 [self.view addSubview:popup_viewforimage];
  [UIView commitAnimations]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
[popup_viewforimage removeFromSuperView];
```

OR

set it's alpha to 0

```
popup_viewforimage.alpha=0.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (UIView *vw in popup_viewforimage.subviews) {
    if ([vw isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
        vw.hidden=YES;
    }
}
```